# How do you create a collection of tables for ruby/Watir and Page Objects

Tags: ruby, watir, pageobjects, page-object-gem

I have a page with a series of dynamic tables.
I want to be able to loop through these tables, convert them to Hash (using the .hashes method) and compare them to data in a .yml file.
But I cant seem to get the collection to work.

Here is one attempt (using a dummy page):

```
class ViewOnlyPages
  include PageObject
  page_url("https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/examples")

  tables(:all_tables, :class =>'google-visualization-table-table')
  def verify_page_against(page_name, dataset)
  #load data from Yml

  #hash spin through all tables (for each table, read each record into hash?)
  self.all_tables.each do |table|
    puts table.hashes
    puts '---'
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tables` accessor method is similar to the `elements` accessor method. Instead of creating an `all_tables` method, the method created is actually `all_tables_elements` (note the "_elements" part).

In other words, the iteration over the tables should be:

```
self.all_tables_elements.each do |table|
  puts table.hashes
  puts '---'
end
```

Note that this will not actually create any output for the sample page. The current definition of the tables assumes that they are in the main page. However, in this case the table is in an iframe. You need to explicitly state when to look in iframes. To get output, the table should be defined within an `in_iframe` block:

```
in_iframe(:class => 'framebox') do |frame|
  tables(:all_tables, :class =>'google-visualization-table-table', :frame => frame)
end
```

Comment: That looks good, thank you.  I have used your page in the past. It is very helpful.  I am getting a deprecation warning on the Hashes method.  Any advice there?

Comment: What version of the page-object gem are you using? The `Table#hashes` method was just added in v1.0.3 (which is the latest release).

Comment: I just traced that back.  Updating my gem now.  Thanks!